# sun-ejb-jar.xml inside a Java EE 6 WAR

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, war, ejb-3.1

One of the greatest features of Java EE 6 is the ability to package EJBs inside a WAR. I've done this for a few projects w/out a hitch, until now.  I'm using Java EE 6, Glassfish 3.1 and deploying my application as a WAR.  I want the ability to control the number of beans that are being created by the app server.  Previously I would do so by specifying the proper values inside the sun-ejb-jar.xml file in my EJB jar which lived in my EAR.

When I put a sun-ejb-jar.xml file in my WAR at /WEB-INF/classes/ it doesn't seem to be honored by Glassfish.

Ideas?

Thanks,
-Jay

Answer (score 1):

I see this in the EJB 3.1 spec.  Chapter 20 'Packaging'; Section 4 (around page 589 of the pdf of the spec that you can download from the JCP site: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/index.html)

> An enterprise bean class with a
>   component-defining annotation defines
>   an enterprise bean component  when
>   packaged within the WEB-INF/classes
>   directory or in a .jar file within
>   WEB-INF/lib. An  enterprise bean can
>   also be defined via
>   WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml.

The first part of this incredibly complex sentence is talking about class files; not the deployment descriptor.

Since the ejb-jar.xml and the sun-ejb-jar.xml file are often seen 'together', you may want to put the file WEB-INF, next to ejb-jar.xml and web.xml.

Comment: Thanks vkraemer, yes I agree, the spec definition is a bit complex. I believe I've figured out the issue. The bean that I'm trying to control is an MDB and I didn't specify that in the deployment descriptor. Doing so seems to work. I don't have the exact behavior I expected but the file does seem to be recognized now.

Answer (score 0):

The bean I am defining is an MDB and I forgot to include the  information. Once I did the file appears to be picked up by Glassfish.